# Read date variable separated by points

Tags: r, datetime, dataset, posixct

My dataset has a variable with date and time, where the days, months and years are separated by points instead of bars.
For example:

```
example <- "13.04.2021 12:00:00"
```

When I convert it to POSIXct it returns NAs, probably due to the points.
Is there any way to change the points into bars so that the function recognizes the variable as date?

Comment: Did you try using the format argument?  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date,  format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS"))

Comment: It is due to not knowing how to include a format argument. Even if you had slashes or dashes as separators the order of the date components was not “standard”. Also possible that you misspelled POSIXct

Comment: This should work: `as.POSIXct("13.04.2021 12:00:00", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will work:

```
as.POSIXct(example, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
lubridate::as_datetime(example, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

For more information, see:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*

or

https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/as_date.html